# Rules Engine Real Time Execution

Tags: rules, rule-engine, business-rules

I am using PHP and MySQL to run a backend server.
Currently I have a "Action" table that contains certain criteria and what action should be taken, the properties are following:

1. `Conditions` (contains complex criteria, e.g. `[Item.Qty] > 100000 AND [User.Level] < 5 AND [Item.Price] > 100000`)
2. `Actions` (e.g. `SEND EMAIL TO [SUPERVISOR]`)

I already have the condition parser that will return boolean.

The software will need to validate *every* user's action to the every rules (e.g. enterprise software). But I have thousands of rules and number of request is high.

Any idea to run this in real-time when user submitting / saving data to the system?

Thanks :)

***Notes:
Since I have tons of feature to compare, decision table is not a feasible option here***

Comment: Parallelization?

Comment: @bbozo I have not tried it, considering the high request, retrieving and running thousand of complex rules one by one on PHP, I am afraid it can slow down the process of the API call to user at the front-end.